# How to delete lines from a file and output the altered file in R?

Tags: python, r, hpc

I have following data. This is the beginning of a large .SAM file. I need to remove the lines 24,25 & 26 and write the output to the same file as a .SAM file. Is there any simple way to do that?

```
@HD     VN:1.0  SO:unsorted
@SQ     SN:10   LN:130694993
@SQ     SN:11   LN:122082543
@SQ     SN:12   LN:120129022
@SQ     SN:13   LN:120421639
@SQ     SN:14   LN:124902244
@SQ     SN:15   LN:104043685
@SQ     SN:16   LN:98207768
@SQ     SN:17   LN:94987271
@SQ     SN:18   LN:90702639
@SQ     SN:19   LN:61431566
@SQ     SN:1    LN:195471971
@SQ     SN:2    LN:182113224
@SQ     SN:3    LN:160039680
@SQ     SN:4    LN:156508116
@SQ     SN:5    LN:151834684
@SQ     SN:6    LN:149736546
@SQ     SN:7    LN:145441459
@SQ     SN:8    LN:129401213
@SQ     SN:9    LN:124595110
@SQ     SN:X    LN:171031299
@SQ     SN:Y    LN:91744698
@PG     ID:bowtie2      PN:bowtie2      VN:2.3.4.1      CL:"/opt/rit/spack-app/linux-rhel7-x86_64/gcc-4.8.5/bowtie2-2.3.4.1-jl5zqymv3rkp64s5oovgymylg5eftfoi/bin/bowtie2-align-s --wrapper basic-0 -x /work/LAS/geetu-lab/hhvu/index_files/mm10/bowtie2-ensembl/mm10 -S /work/LAS/geetu-lab/hhvu/project1/chip-seq/1_bowtie2/I10_S64_L005.bam -U I10_S64_L005_R1_001.fastq"
@PG     ID:bowtie2-2F3DB176     PN:bowtie2      VN:2.3.4.1      CL:"/opt/rit/spack-app/linux-rhel7-x86_64/gcc-4.8.5/bowtie2-2.3.4.1-jl5zqymv3rkp64s5oovgymylg5eftfoi/bin/bowtie2-align-s --wrapper basic-0 -x /work/LAS/geetu-lab/hhvu/index_files/mm10/bowtie2-ensembl/mm10 -S /work/LAS/geetu-lab/hhvu/project1/chip-seq/1_bowtie2/I10_S64_L006.bam -U I10_S64_L006_R1_001.fastq"
@PG     ID:bowtie2-54BA705F     PN:bowtie2      VN:2.3.4.1      CL:"/opt/rit/spack-app/linux-rhel7-x86_64/gcc-4.8.5/bowtie2-2.3.4.1-jl5zqymv3rkp64s5oovgymylg5eftfoi/bin/bowtie2-align-s --wrapper basic-0 -x /work/LAS/geetu-lab/hhvu/index_files/mm10/bowtie2-ensembl/mm10 -S /work/LAS/geetu-lab/hhvu/project1/chip-seq/1_bowtie2/I10_S64_L007.bam -U I10_S64_L007_R1_001.fastq"
@PG     ID:bowtie2-31E64087     PN:bowtie2      VN:2.3.4.1      CL:"/opt/rit/spack-app/linux-rhel7-x86_64/gcc-4.8.5/bowtie2-2.3.4.1-jl5zqymv3rkp64s5oovgymylg5eftfoi/bin/bowtie2-align-s --wrapper basic-0 -x /work/LAS/geetu-lab/hhvu/index_files/mm10/bowtie2-ensembl/mm10 -S /work/LAS/geetu-lab/hhvu/project1/chip-seq/1_bowtie2/I10_S64_L008.bam -U I10_S64_L008_R1_001.fastq"
J00102:65:HF3WFBBXY:6:1101:2777:1806    16      12      77384783        1       50M     *       0       0       TCCTTTCCCAATCTGTTGGTGGTCTTTTTGTCTTACTGACGGTGTCTTTT      FFJFF7JJJFAJJJFJJJFA-JJJJJJJJFFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFAFAA      AS:i:0  XS:i:0  XN:i:0  XM:i:0  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:0  MD:Z:50 YT:Z:UU
J00102:65:HF3WFBBXY:8:1101:2341:1965    0       13      73416403        40      50M     *       0       0       GAGAAGGGAAGGGAACAATTGGAAGGGGGATTTGTGAGATGACGATTGGG      AAF<AFJ<7FFJJJJFFJJJJJJ<JJJJJA<FFJF-<A7<-F-<7-<A-A      AS:i:-6 XN:i:0  XM:i:2  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:2  MD:Z:40C1A7     YT:Z:UU
```

Comment: Do you *actually* have a SAM file? The first order of business would be to convert it to a BAM file and then to delete the text file: SAM is meant to be an intermediate format, it’s not meant to be stored. It is too inefficient and unwieldy for that. For working with BAM files in R there are packages on Bioconductor, e.g. Rsamtools.

Comment: Actually I'm trying call peaks in chip-seq analysis. I have combined four SAM files from four technical replicates/lanes and got one SAM file. (Above data file is the combined one) At the first place, SAM file is the one I received for peak calling from another person (After the alignment step). I did not convert it since it can be used directly for peak calling.

Comment: Regardless, this is a really bad idea. Use BAM files. That other person should be giving you BAM files instead of SAM files to begin with.

Comment: below code actually does not work for the original large SAM file. So you are suggesting to convert SAM files into BAM files, then use Bioconductor? I'm using HPC.

Answer (score 1):

Read file as a vector of strings:

```
file_path <- "foo.SAM"
fh <- file(file_path)
file_content <- readLines(fh)
close(fh)
```

Edit the string vector:

```
new_content <- file_content[-c(24, 25, 26), ]
```

Write collapsed string vector back to disk:

```
cat(paste0(new_content, collapse="\n"), file="foo.SAM", "\n")
```

Comment: SAM files are in the order of several (up to hundreds of) gigabytes. You absolutely cannot read them in all at once.

Comment: It worked for the shorter file actually. Need to try it with the original file.

Comment: If the file is indeed several gigabytes you won't be able to load it all at once into memory (depending on your setup). There are alternatives to the approach I suggested. Maybe `data.table::fread` or  [bigreadr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigreadr/bigreadr.pdf) ?? Sorry that I couldn't help you with your particular problem (I was also not familiar with the .SAM file format)